# Spring Rest + JPA 2.0 Transaction Management - Return null value to delete

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa

I get `Object: null is not a known entity type.` error. I think, there are missing configuration in my `Spring Rest + JPA` application.

In my code `Operator operator = em.find(Operator.class, operatorId);`, `return null value.` Sorry for my long code.

OperatorDAO.java

```
package com.ignite.easyticket.core.operator.persistence;

@Repository("OperatorDAO")
public class OperatorDAO extends BasicDAO implements IOperatorDAO {

    ...

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void delete(String operatorId) throws DAOException {
        try {
            logger.debug("delete() method has been started.");
            Operator operator = em.find(Operator.class, operatorId); // <- Here always return null value, I am sure there is a record with id
            em.remove(operator);
            em.flush();
            logger.debug("delete() method has been successfully finisehd.");
        } catch (PersistenceException pe) {
            logger.error("delete() method has been failed.", pe);
            throw translate("Failed to update Operator", pe);
        }
    }
}
```

OperatorService.java

```
package com.ignite.easyticket.core.operator.service;

@Service(value = "OperatorService")
public class OperatorService implements IOperatorService {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Resource(name = "OperatorDAO")
    private IOperatorDAO operatorDAO;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void deleteOperator(String operatorId) throws SystemException {
        try {
            logger.debug("deleteOperator() method has been started.");
            operatorDAO.delete(operatorId);
            logger.debug("deleteOperator() method has been successfully finisehd.");
        } catch (DAOException e) {
            logger.error("deleteOperator() method has been failed.");
            throw new SystemException(e.getErrorCode(), "Faield to delete a Operator", e);
        }
    }   
}
```

OperatorController.java
    package com.ignite.easyticket.webservice;

```
@Controller
public class OperatorController {
    @RequestMapping(value = URIConstant.OPERATOR_DELETE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    void deleteOperator(@RequestBody String operatorId) {
        logger.info("deleteOperator() proces has been started...");
        operatorService.deleteOperator(operatorId);
        logger.info("deleteOperator() proces has been finished...");
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans....>
    <import resource="spring-beans.xml" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ignite.easyticket.webservice" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
</beans>
```

spring-beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ignite.easyticket.core"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <util:properties id="SQL_ERROR_CODE" location="classpath:SQL_ERROR_CODE.properties"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="JPA"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <props>
                <prop key="eclipselink.weaving">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver">
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">

        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="com.ignite.easyticket.core.common.SystemException">System Error!</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>
</beans>
```

Full Stack Trace

```
17:15:18,452 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing POST request for [/easyticket/operator/delete]
17:15:18,452 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] Looking up handler method for path /operator/delete
17:15:18,452 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing GET request for [/easyticket/operator/findall]
17:15:18,452 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] Looking up handler method for path /operator/findall
17:15:18,452 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] Returning handler method [public void com.ignite.easyticket.webservic
e.OperatorController.deleteOperator(java.lang.String)]
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'operatorController'
17:15:18,452 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] Returning handler method [public java.util.List<com.ignite.easyticket
.core.operator.Operator> com.ignite.easyticket.webservice.OperatorController.findAllOperator()]
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'operatorController'
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] Last-Modified value for [/easyticket/operator/findall] is: -1
17:15:18,454 INFO  [com.ignite.easyticket.webservice.OperatorController] findAllOperator() proces has been started...
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Creating new transaction with name [com.ignite.easyticket.core.operator.service.OperatorService.findAl
lOperator]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor] Reading [java.lang.String] as "application/json;charset=utf-8" 
using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@1b3d448]
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Opened new EntityManager [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@354949] for JPA trans
action
17:15:18,454 INFO  [com.ignite.easyticket.webservice.OperatorController] deleteOperator() proces has been started...
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [com.ignite.easyticket.core.operator.service.OperatorService] findAllOperator() method has been started.
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Creating new transaction with name [com.ignite.easyticket.core.operator.service.OperatorService.delete
Operator]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@354949] for J
PA transaction
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Opened new EntityManager [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@5e88f7] for JPA trans
action
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Participating in existing transaction
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [com.ignite.easyticket.core.operator.service.OperatorService] deleteOperator() method has been started.
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@5e88f7] for J
PA transaction
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Participating in existing transaction
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [com.ignite.easyticket.core.operator.persistence.OperatorDAO] findAll() method has been started.
17:15:18,454 DEBUG [com.ignite.easyticket.core.operator.persistence.OperatorDAO] delete() method has been started.
[EL Config]: connection: 2014-10-31 17:15:18.454--ServerSession(17807976)--Connection(7484998)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-3,5,main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>MySQLPlatform
    user name=> "spangular"
    datasource URL=> "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spangular"
))
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-10-31 17:15:18.454--ClientSession(4796401)--Connection(6084601)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main])--SELECT ID, ADDRESS, BANKACCOUNT, NAME, PHO
NE, VERSION FROM OPERATOR
17:15:18,457 DEBUG [com.ignite.easyticket.core.operator.persistence.OperatorDAO] findAll() method has been started.
17:15:18,457 DEBUG [com.ignite.easyticket.core.operator.service.OperatorService] findAllOperator() method has been successfully finisehd.
17:15:18,457 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Initiating transaction commit
17:15:18,457 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@35
4949]
[EL Config]: connection: 2014-10-31 17:15:18.463--ServerSession(17807976)--Connection(14393847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-3,5,main])--Connected: jdbc:mysql://localho
st:3306/spangular
    User: spangular@localhost
    Database: MySQL  Version: 5.6.14-log
    Driver: MySQL-AB JDBC Driver  Version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.6 ( Revision: ${svn.Revision} )
17:15:18,463 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Closing JPA EntityManager [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@354949] after transa
ction
17:15:18,463 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils] Closing JPA EntityManager
17:15:18,463 INFO  [com.ignite.easyticket.webservice.OperatorController] findAllOperator() proces has been finished...
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-10-31 17:15:18.463--ClientSession(23489242)--Connection(14393847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-3,5,main])--SELECT ID, ADDRESS, BANKACCOUNT, NAME, P
HONE, VERSION FROM OPERATOR WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [{"id":"OPE000000000001"}]
17:15:18,463 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only
17:15:18,465 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Setting JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@5e88f
7] rollback-only
17:15:18,465 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Initiating transaction rollback
17:15:18,465 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@
5e88f7]
17:15:18,465 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor] Written [[com.ignite.easyticket.core.operator.Operator@4468130e
, com.ignite.easyticket.core.operator.Operator@2d068d15]] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConver
ter@14c7f77]
17:15:18,465 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter comple
ted request handling
17:15:18,465 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] Successfully completed request
17:15:18,465 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Closing JPA EntityManager [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@5e88f7] after transa
ction
17:15:18,465 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils] Closing JPA EntityManager
17:15:18,465 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [public void com.ignite.easytic
ket.webservice.OperatorController.deleteOperator(java.lang.String)]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: null is not a known entity type.
17:15:18,465 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [public void com.ignite.easyticket.webse
rvice.OperatorController.deleteOperator(java.lang.String)]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: null is not a known entity type.
17:15:18,465 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [public void com.ignite.easyticket.webservi
ce.OperatorController.deleteOperator(java.lang.String)]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: null is not a known entity type.
17:15:18,465 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [public void com.ignite.easyticket.webservice.Op
eratorController.deleteOperator(java.lang.String)]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: null is not a known entity type.
17:15:18,465 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] Could not complete request
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: null is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.remove(EntityManagerImpl.java:560)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
    at $Proxy17.remove(Unknown Source)
    at com.ignite.easyticket.core.operator.persistence.OperatorDAO.delete(OperatorDAO.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy26.delete(Unknown Source)
    at com.ignite.easyticket.core.operator.service.OperatorService.deleteOperator(OperatorService.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy27.deleteOperator(Unknown Source)
    at com.ignite.easyticket.webservice.OperatorController.deleteOperator(OperatorController.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Oct 31, 2014 5:15:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/easyticket] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgume
ntException: Object: null is not a known entity type.] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: null is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.remove(EntityManagerImpl.java:560)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
    at $Proxy17.remove(Unknown Source)
    at com.ignite.easyticket.core.operator.persistence.OperatorDAO.delete(OperatorDAO.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy26.delete(Unknown Source)
    at com.ignite.easyticket.core.operator.service.OperatorService.deleteOperator(OperatorService.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy27.deleteOperator(Unknown Source)
    at com.ignite.easyticket.webservice.OperatorController.deleteOperator(OperatorController.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

**Upate**

For more sure to check DB

[image]

Comment: Could you log the `operatorId` in `OperatorDAO.delete` ? Something like : `logger.debug("delete() method has been started with >" + operatorId + "<");`

Comment: @SergeBallesta In my stack trace, there is a log `SELECT ID, ADDRESS, BANKACCOUNT, NAME, PHONE, VERSION FROM OPERATOR WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [{"id":"OPE000000000001"}]`. I am sure there is a record with that id

Comment: In the logs, there is `findAllOperator() proces has been finished...` and then `Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only`. Any idea why the transaction rolled back? Does `SELECT ID, ADDRESS, BANKACCOUNT, NAME, PHONE, VERSION FROM OPERATOR WHERE (ID = 'OPE000000000001')` work when executed directly in the database?

Comment: @PredragMaric,  Yes, Transaction is rolled back. What I think is, because of select record is null. Query work when executed directly in the database.

Comment: Does `SELECT ID, ADDRESS, BANKACCOUNT, NAME, PHONE, VERSION FROM OPERATOR WHERE (ID = 'OPE000000000001')` work in the db? Judging from the logs, you are calling `getAllOperators()` prior to this, almost in the same millisecond, could there be some transaction overlapping? could you isolate your test case just to `deleteOperator()`, maybe even with hard coded id?

Comment: Can you add the code of you Entity (Operator.java)?

Comment: @Xstian, I cannot add anymore, boz, i reach mx lenth(30000) of StackOverflow.. Sorry

Comment: @CycDemo No problem :) but I've some doubts on primarykey that you used, can tell us java type and annotation used?

Comment: @Xstian, use `@Transient` for id field. `
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "OPERATOR_GEN")
  @Access(value = AccessType.PROPERTY)` for id setter method

Comment: I think that you should remove @Transient because is used to indicate that a field is not to be persisted in the database. The find operation is based on PrimaryKey, if is transient i think that doesn't work fine.

Comment: It is a pleasure to help you. Let me know :)